# android: ksoap2 org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG exception

Tags: android, exception, ksoap2

I am trying to get a response from a web service. However I am getting some exception errors: mainly this one

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@1:6 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40524b78)
```

Actually I am trying to access a method of a web-service and the webservice is supposed to return two strings (Lets say String1 and String2). Moreover, I have to provide or pass two parameters (lets say Parameter 1 and Parameter 2 where Parameter 1 should be integer and Parameter 2 should be String) Here is my code

```
public class MyWebService extends Activity {

private static final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://www.mywebsite.com/myMethod";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "MyMethod";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.myNamespace/";
    private static final String URL = "http://mysession.com/myservice.asmx?WSDL";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();   
        pi.setName("Parameter 1");
        pi.setValue(1);
        pi.setType(pi.INTEGER_CLASS);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();  
        pi2.setName("Parameter 2");
        pi2.setValue("Any string");
        pi2.setType(pi2.STRING_CLASS);
        request.addProperty(pi2);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new  SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                   
        //SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();             
        SoapPrimitive  result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        String resultData = result.toString();

        //String string1=result.getProperty(0).toString();
        //String string2=result.getProperty(1).toString();

        Log.v("WEBSERVICE","RESPONSE: "+resultData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    

    }        
}
```

}

Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong here.. Another very important question: 
Can anyone tell me that why I can't use getProperty(0) or getProperty(1) method with the result here. I am supposed to get two strings in response from webservice but I can't use getProperty(index) with SoapPrimitive.. 
All suggestions are appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: First of all change your url to `http://mysession.com/myservice.asmx`.After please check that your `SOAP_ACTION`,`METHOD_NAME` & `NAMESPACE` is correct,usually the `SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is exact solution what you need but this works for me, I was getting same problem before, but There was 5 parameters needed and I just added 3 parameters using SoapObject, so it was giving this type of error, so please make sure that you have added all required parameters using *request.addProperty("test","test")* before call this webservice.